# Can I open 'Light Bulb Suggestions' programatically and invoke 'Add using statement...'?

Tags: c#, vsix

I am playing around with VSIX development, and I wanted to know if it's possible to open the 'Light bulb' suggestions and invoke the 'Using ....' action on a ProjectItem object?